# Ambiguous meaning for a comma?

Tags: commas, ambiguity

I saw the following on a bottle of soy sauce, and don't know if it could be interpreted multiple ways:

> No artificial colour, flavour added

The question is if flavour is added or not.

The comma could be interpreted as `and` or `or`:

> No artificial colour or flavour added

That would mean no artificial colour was added. But I could also interpret it as two unrelated statements:

> No artificial colour. Flavour added

That means flavour was added.

Am I missing something here, or could the comma be ambiguous in this case? What is the actual meaning of the sentence?

Comment: Product labels are even less useful than newspaper headlines in terms of helping non-native speakers learn anything about "correct" English grammar! In practice there's no ambiguity here, though. Why would a manufacturer want to "boast" that they don't use artificial *colour*, but they *do* use artificial ***flavour**?*

Comment: @Polygorial: You mean lawyers like Lionel Hutz? (“Works on contingency?  No, money down!”)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct. It's a bit unusual for only two conjuncts to be connected by a comma, but in some contexts it's entirely normal. Thus, your first interpretation ("no artificial colour or flavour added") is certainly possible.

The second interpretation is basically a comma splice, but that is not so unusual here since the entire phrase is written in "headlinese". (It contains no finite verbs and can be considered to consist entirely of noun phrases.)

This issue could have been easily avoided by using a conjunction or a different punctuation mark (period or semicolon) instead of a comma. I can't tell whether it's simply poor writing or deliberate obfuscation (as suggested in a comment above).

You wrote "The question is if artificial flavour is added or not." I'll just note that in the second interpretation the word "artificial" doesn't apply to "flavor". (You put "artificial" in parentheses later, so I guess that you recognized that.)

Comment: Upvoted, but I don't agree your final paragraph. Imho it would be perverse to interpret ***flavour*** as meaning ***non-artificial** flavour*, regardless of whether preceding negation extends to the second element (which in practice it obviously *does* in this exact context).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Are you basing that on the langauge or on outside knowledge? (My culinary skills are nearly non-existent, so AFAIK added flavor could be artificial or natural.)

Comment: The message is ill-defined and could etically (without pragmatic interpretational skills) mean any of 'No flavour or artificial colour added', 'No artificial colour or artificial flavour added' or 'No artificial colour. Flavour has been added'. Doubtless lawyers would have a field day arguing over these.

Comment: The meaning of "perverse interpretation" should be obvious. Virtually all use of natural language is either meaningless or ambiguous if not interpreted in the context of "outside knowledge" about what makes sense in the real world. There''s no chance of a "grammatical rule" to tell us what OP's cited usage "means" - it's not even syntactically or orthographically "valid" in the first place!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Don't we have some context, though? OP said it was "on a bottle of soy sauce". And although the syntax may not be "valid" in commonly spoken English, headlinese is usually quite understandable; headline (and product label) writers certainly wouldn't use it otherwise. This just seems to be one particular case in which it's ambiguous.

Comment: <sigh> It's *not* ambiguous! Part of the context is we can assume the company making and labeling the product aren't complete morons, *and* we can assume they don't think their customers are either. What kind of customers would want to buy from a company that brags about not using artificial colouring *at the same time as* pointing out that they *do* use artificial flavouring?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Perhaps a company that was forced to state something due to labelling requirements, or perhaps a company that made a mistake. (It would hardly be the first time an error has ever appeared on a label.) I really don't think that we can be 100% certain.